# Index If function with 2 or multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to use the index formula on multiple columns? For Sheet 1, its manually being updated(Column A, B and C) by our team so we need the task list for our pending IDs. Please see the table link below, problem is... we want to only see the IDs If column B and C is blank.

We want to keep the index function if possible as we need the IDs to not shift up and mix with the other person list. (if there's another formula feel free to share)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VdKk1GBK0tew10nys-QHHrD2amfk6gddhweydZY7gjo/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking! I've edited my post.

Comment: The question remains unclear. Manually enter the desired results you would like to see in the sample spreadsheet column `Problem!B3:B`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time! I've edited the sheet for the desired output.

Comment: Your question remains unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list column `Sheet1!A1:A` rows where columns `Sheet1!B1:B` and `Sheet1!C1:C` are both blank, showing a blank result on rows where either `B` or `C` contain a value, use `if()` in an array formula, like this:

`=arrayformula( if( isblank(Sheet1!B1:B) + isblank(Sheet1!C1:C), Sheet1!A1:A, iferror(1/0) ) )`

To list column `Sheet1!A2:A` rows where column `Sheet1!B2:B` and `Sheet1!C2:C` both contain a date, omitting rows that do not match, use `filter()`, like this:

`=filter(Sheet1!A2:A, isnumber(Sheet1!B2:B) * isnumber(Sheet1!C2:C))`

To list column `Sheet1!A2:A` rows where column `Sheet1!B2:B` and `Sheet1!C2:C` both contain a date, showing blank with rows that do not match, use:

`=arrayformula( if( isnumber(Sheet1!B2:B) * isnumber(Sheet1!C2:C), Sheet1!A2:A, iferror(1/0) ) )`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for providing a solution. However, we only need the Order IDs to show if there is no/blank input on either/both columns. Apologies if my question is unclear. Also, we're using index function so that the IDs wont shift up.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time! I've edited the sheet for the desired output.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/167330/edit) the question to clarify that you are trying to only show rows where both B and C are blank.

Comment: This is exactly what we need. Thanks a lot!